# Assign arbitrary color to monochrome image within browser

Tags: javascript, css, colors

Let's say I have an image that contains only red and transparent pixels:

[image: red-and-transparent image]

Now I want the red pixels to show up as *any color I choose*. Is this possible with something like `-webkit-filter`? I already know how to assign it an arbitrary hue (`hue-rotate(Ndeg)`) and how to make it darker (`brightness(N%)`), but making it lighter (i.e. pink) eludes me. `brightness(200%)` has no apparent effect. I've also tried starting from a white image, but I can't seem to saturate it.

If there is a JavaScript library that converts any hex color to a series of CSS filters (or anything else that accomplishes this task), that would be optimal, but I doubt such a library exists. I might write one myself if I can figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a canvas to change the color:

[image: Changed color of image]

For example - just dry isolated code but adjust as needed:

```
/// draw image onto canvas of same size as image
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

/// KEY: change composite mode
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-in';

/// pick any color you want
ctx.fillStyle = '#00f';

/// draw rectangle on top with fill style - only solid pixels will change
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

**[Here is an online demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/aeztd/).**

The composite mode used here will make sure only solid colors are filled; the transparent pixels will remain transparent. You could fill with anything really, gradient, another image and so on.

After this is complete you can now either use the on-screen canvas as-is (it will show as an image) or you can get a data-uri from the canvas which you can set as source for another image element by using 'canvas.toDataURL()` however for this last to work you need to fulfill [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) requirement. The simplest is to use the canvas directly.

Comment: I've decided to implement this, acknowledging the additional CORS requirement, and it's working perfectly so far. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the `opacity` filter? Although not exactly what you may want (i.e. a lightness filter), the following gives me pink in the above situation:

```
img {
    -webkit-filter: opacity(30%);
}
```

See the following: http://codepen.io/micjamking/pen/222c540689d92ec1df1a3b6e1ea2933f

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't assume that the background will be white, so this doesn't quite work for me. However, I *could* try loading the image twice, one directly above the other, and using `-webkit-filter: saturate(0%) brightness(500%)` to make the bottom image's red pixels appear white, then apply the opacity filter to the top image. I'll report back if this works in enough cases for me.